# How to convert Xpath syntax to XSL/XSLT syntax?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I understand how XPath syntax works, and can write Xpath commands to extract certain information from a XML file.
I would like to convert my XPath commands to XSLT scripts so that someone else can just run the script over the XML file to get the same output.

e.g.

I have a XML file that, let's say, looks like follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <library>
        <section id="109196796">
            <master_information>
                <shelf_identifier>
                    <identifier type="CodeX" type_id="2">LB1500605917</identifier>
                    <identifier type="Common Code" type_id="15">150060591</identifier>
                </shelf_identifier>
                <shelf_master>
                    <section_type>1</section_type>
                    <book_type>3</book_type>
                </shelf_master>
            </master_information>
        </section>
        <section id="109196798">
            <master_information>
                <shelf_identifier>
                    <identifier type="CodeX" type_id="2">LB0777775917</identifier>
                    <identifier type="Common Code" type_id="15">077777591</identifier>
                </shelf_identifier>
                <shelf_master>
                    <section_type>1</section_type>
                    <book_type>3</book_type>
                </shelf_master>
            </master_information>
        </section>
        <section id="109196800">
            <master_information>
                <shelf_identifier>
                    <identifier type="CodeX" type_id="2">LB2589165917</identifier>
                    <identifier type="Common Code" type_id="15">258916591</identifier>
                </shelf_identifier>
                <shelf_master>
                    <section_type>1</section_type>
                    <book_type>3</book_type>
                </shelf_master>
            </master_information>
        </section>
  </library>
```

If I run the XPath command below,

```
//identifier[@type='CodeX']
```

I get the output:

```
LB1500605917
LB0777775917
LB2589165917
```

..which is expected. Now, I tried converting the XPath command to an XSL syntax as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="return">
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text> <!-- defined a line break -->
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="//library"></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//section/master_information/shelf_identifier/identifier"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="@type='CodeX'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$return"/> <!-- this basically puts a line break -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSL seems to be correct. However, no output is generated.

I am new to XSL/XSLT. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using only one template or specifying the xpath on value-of select??

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried removing the template for library and changing the second one to "//identifier"
I get the following output:true
false
13true
false
13true
false
13

Which doesn't make sense since they are not even present in the file.

Comment: @Pernambuco - If you use the same XPath (`//identifier[@type='CodeX']`) in an xsl:value-of select, and you're using XSLT 1.0, you'll only get the first value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is add a template matching the same nodes as your xpath, then outputting the value along with a newline...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <!--The strip-space isn't completely necessary. I just always include it in my
  default stylesheets. It strips whitespace. You can preserve whitespace with
  xsl:preserve-space. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip for more details.-->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Suppress output of text nodes by built-in templates.-->
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

  <!--Match "indentifier" elements that contain a "type" attribute
  with the value of "CodeX".-->
  <xsl:template match="identifier[@type='CodeX']">
    <!--Output the value of the current context ("identifier") concatenated with
    a newline. ("&#xA;" is a hex entity reference. You could also use a decimal
    reference ("&#10;")). You could use either of these references as the value
    of a variable too (or even declare it as an entity).
    I use normalize-space() instead of . to clean up any additional spaces.
    See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space for details.-->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(),'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice the empty template that matches `text()`. This is added to suppress the output of text() nodes by XSLT's [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).

Also note that I didn't use `//` in my match. This is also because of the built-in rules; they allow recursive processing by default.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you so much for responding. Your script worked like a charm! 
I am still trying to understand the changes you made though. If it is not too much to ask, can you add comments explaining in short what does every line that you changed does? That will be very helpful. I will look into the built-in template rules - that's new to me. Thank you!

Comment: @Fenil - Sure no problem.  I'll edit in a few minutes.

Comment: @ Daniel Thanks again!

Comment: @Fenil - I added some comments. If you still have questions, let me know. The "built-in" link will help to understand how XSLT works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//identifier[@type='CodeX']">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your script works too! I didn't know until today that we can directly put in Xpath commands in the select field. That's good to know. I have already accepted an answer from someone else. Thanks for responding!

Comment: "I didn't know until today..." - Remarks like that terrify me. Did you teach yourself XSLT just by looking at other people's code? Is that the way you learnt to drive a car?

Comment: @MichaelKay Haha, no. I was thrown into XSLT, and learning on the fly but haven't gotten to learn it the formal way. We all don't really learn EVERYTHING the way we learn other things, do we? :)